# Creating Azure Bus Service using Azure Powershell throwing exception

Tags: azure, powershell, azureservicebus

I'm trying to create Azure Service Bus using Azure powershell command.

I'm using command as :

```
New-AzureSBNamespace –Name UKBProjectServiceBus -Location "West US" -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging
```

But getting exception as:

> New-AzureSBNamespace : InternalError: The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AzureSBNamespace -Name UKBProjectServiceBus -Location "West US" - ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBNamespace], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBNamespaceCommand
>   Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I believe you're using a really old PowerShell Cmdlet. Please use `New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace` instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-manage-with-ps#provision-a-service-bus-namespace).

Comment: you could also consider `New-AzServiceBusNamespace` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusnamespace?view=azps-1.6.0 .. on a side note you're trying to create an ACS namespace as well, which is retired too by now I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This PowerShell command for Service Bus will **no longer be supported on 11/1/2019**. The Azure Service Management model **is deprecated for Service Bus**, and will be disabled on that date. Please use the commands which support the Azure Resource Management model in AzureRM.ServiceBus.

As Gaurav and Rohit said, the [New-AzureSBNamespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/new-azuresbnamespace?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) is a really old Powershell Cmdlet to use.

You could use `New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup $ResGrpName -NamespaceName $Namespace -Location $Location` to create Azure ServiceBus. Refer to this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-manage-with-ps#provision-a-service-bus-namespace).
[image]

Or use `New-AzServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroupName Default-ServiceBus-WestUS -Name SB-Example1 -Location WestUS` to create Azure ServiceBus. Refer to this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusnamespace?view=azps-1.6.0).
[image]